# Adding Trailing Zeros to Decimal Places

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column where numerical data is stored (in thousands) with a '.' signifying a thousands separator. The initial input file lacks trailing zeros, and a trailing decimal places are needed (to a maximum of 3). Whole numbers should remain the same.

Please find a snippet of the dataframe `df` below.

Input Data

```
Product     Quantity 
ABC         1
ZXC         2.1
QWE         3.21
ASD         4.123
```

Expected output

```
Product     Quantity 
ABC         1
ZXC         2.100
QWE         3.210
ASD         4.123
```

Any assistance that anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can change float display format in a following way:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.3f}'.format
```

If you don't want integers to be formatted, use following:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = lambda x: '{:,.0f}'.format(x) if float(x.is_integer()) else '{:,.3f}'.format(x)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Where exactly in my script should I place this line of code? When attempting to set a this line to a specific column I get the following error. `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: You can place this line in the very beginning of the script (e.g. after imports) and it should affect how float numbers will be displayed along the whole script.

Comment: This solution won't work unfortunately as `1` now appears as `1.000`, which now signifies 1000 as `.` is my thousands separator.

Comment: Updated answer with an example of integer handling